How do I fix misalignment in an HTML email with a image and a centered number inside?
"I need to send the HTML template in an email. In the HTML, there's a polygon-shaped image, and the image inside place number should be centered. However, when sending the mail, the image inside number is misaligned. How can I fix it?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr style="display: flex; justify-content: center; margin:0 60px 35px 60px">
          <td align="start" valign="start" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <p style="color:#181C32; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; margin-bottom:13px">What’s next?</p>
            <div style="background: #F9F9F9; border-radius: 12px; padding:35px 30px">
              <div style="display:flex">
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-right: 13px; position: relative;">
                  <img alt="container" src="https://dev-beta.becomeaskiller.com/assets/mail/icon-polygon.png" />
                  <span ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- style="position: absolute; color: #50CD89; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">1</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style="display:flex">
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-right: 13px; position: relative;">
                  <img alt="container" src="https://dev-beta.becomeaskiller.com/assets/mail/icon-polygon.png" />
                  <span style="position: absolute; color: #50CD89; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">2</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style="display:flex">
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-right: 13px; position: relative;">
                  <img alt="container" src="https://dev-beta.becomeaskiller.com/assets/mail/icon-polygon.png" />
                  <span style="position: absolute; color: #50CD89; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">3</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



When sending an HTML template via email, I've noticed that the polygon-shaped image with a number inside is misaligned. How can I ensure that the number inside the image is centered correctly in the email?

Make a polygon shaped image with a number in it

but my manager, don't do  i want image inside set numer 1 value they told.

Convince him it is the simplest. icon-polygon1.png, icon-polygon2.png etc

I am not sure what you want to achieve but this is a simplified version of your sample doing something similar to what I understand is needed.
The point is to use the image as a background on the div containing the number, and use flex attributes to center the number properly. It should ensure that the number always stands in the middle of the image.


.container {
  background: #AAA; 
  border-radius: 12px; 
  padding: 35px 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.tile {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  width: 40px; 
  height: 40px; 
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://dev-beta.becomeaskiller.com/assets/mail/icon-polygon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  
}
.tile-number {
  color: #50CD89; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: 600;
}
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr style="display: flex; justify-content: center; margin:0 60px 35px 60px">
          <td align="start" valign="start" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <p style="color:#181C32; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; margin-bottom:13px">
              What’s next?
            </p>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="tile">
                <span class="tile-number">1</span>
              </div>
              <div class="tile">
                <span class="tile-number">2</span>
              </div>
              <div class="tile">
                <span class="tile-number">3</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




the is mail via come css property not working mam

What do you mean ?

When I placed a number in the center of the image and tried sending the HTML in an email, the alignment didn't work.
